# 404 When Trying to implement Utils in Power BI Custom Visual

Tags: data-visualization, powerbi

I've run into this problem several times when trying to import external libraries to run with a Power BI custom visual, and I'm not really sure what I'm doing wrong. This current attempt is recreating the Card Visual in the latest API, and it's been a painstaking effort that hopefully someone else can help me out with. I can't point at any one reason why this is happening though it appears to be caused by using statements like:

```
import valueFormatter = powerbi.extensibility.utils.formatting.valueFormatter;
```

and I get error, in the browser:

```
Unable to get property 'valueFormatter' of undefined or null reference
visualSandboxMinimal.html (626,17)
```

when I tried removing these things I instead run into the error:

```
HTTP404: NOT FOUND - The server has not found anything matching the requested URI (Uniform Resource Identifier).
(XHR)GET - https://app.powerbi.com/13.0.3328.205/visual.js.map;
```

I can't really resolve either of these errors, to make the project work. The project will build fine and display in the application, but not show any information. Something isn't setup with the API or the project where it just doesn't put the pieces together properly or something. I really don't know and there's so little information out there about this thing, that it's kind of like shouting in the dark at this point.

I am including the whole source project, hopefully so that anyone who can help will be able to, and if anyone wants to take my effort and build their own "Card" like Power BI visual: https://www.dropbox.com/s/9ks8u0v56eph8ul/cardWithConditionalFormatting.zip?dl=0 . This is based on the source available at https://github.com/Microsoft/PowerBI-visuals-core, specifically related to the Card visual.

If anyone figures this out, it would be a huge help to me, though I will continue to do my own research and if I find anything about it I will update the information here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what was happening here, I had included the index.d.ts files in the tsconfig.json file, but forgot to include the index.js files in the pbiviz.json file and in some cases forgot to include the css files in the .less file.